# Why does `mypy --strict` not throw an error in this simple code?

Tags: python, types, type-hinting, mypy

I have the following in `test.py`:

```
def f(x: int) -> float:
    pass

if __name__=="__main__":
  f(4)
```

When I run `mypy --strict test.py`, I get no errors.

I expected `mypy` would be able to infer that there is a problem with my definition `f`. It obviously has no `return` statement and can never return a float.

I feel like there is something fundamental which I do not understand here. The presence (or not) of a `return` statement is something that can be checked statically. Why does `mypy` miss it?

Comment: I believe this is related to the fact, that Your function does literally nothing. As soon as You put in any other function like print(""), mypy raises missing return statement. Mypy would check for type if function can even throw exception, which in Your case can't happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax you use is recognized as a function stub, not as a function implementation.

Normally, a function stub is written as:

```py
def f(x: int) -> float: ...
```

but this is merely a convenience for

```py
def f(x: int) -> float: pass
```

From the mypy [documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/stubs.html#stub-file-syntax):

> Function bodies cannot be completely removed. By convention, we replace them with `...` instead of the `pass` statement.

As mypy does no checks for the function body for stubs, you get no error in this case. And as pointed out by @domarm in the comments, adding any statement besides `pass` (even a second `pass` statement) to the function body will result in the expected mypy error.